# could not be changed because the data didn't validate. (Django)

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

Models.py

```
class Produto(models.Model):
      uuid = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, editable=False, default=gen_uuid)
      produto = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, verbose_name="Item")

      class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Produto"
            verbose_name_plural = "Produtos"

class Item(models.Model):
      uuid = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, editable=False, default=gen_uuid)
      tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, unique=False, verbose_name="tipo_mtr")

      class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Item"
            verbose_name_plural = "Itens"

class Orcamento(models.Model):
      uuid              = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, editable=False, default=gen_uuid)
      quantidade        = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, unique=False, null=True, verbose_name="qtde")
      produto           = models.ForeignKey(Produto, verbose_name="Produto")
      tipo              = models.ManyToManyField(Item, verbose_name="Item")

      class Meta:
              verbose_name = "Orcamento"
              verbose_name_plural = "Orcamentos"
              unique_together     = ("produto", "uuid")

      def __unicode__(self):
         return unicode(self.produto)
```

My forms.py (OrcamentoForm)

```
class OrcamentoForm(ModelForm):
      tipo_id               = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), required=True, widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={"style":"width:500px",}), help_text="Coloque o Tipo de Medida - Requerido")
      quantidade            = IntegerField(label="Quantidade", required=True, help_text="Coloque a Quantidade - Requerido")
      produto_id            = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Produto.objects.all(), widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={"style":"width:500px",}), required=True, help_text="Escolha o Produto - Requerido")

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrcamentoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # without the next line label_from_instance does NOT work 
        self.fields['produto_id'].queryset = Produto.objects.all()
        self.fields['produto_id'].label_from_instance = lambda Produto: "%s" % (Produto.produto)

        self.fields['tipo_id'].queryset = Item.objects.all()
        self.fields['tipo_id'].label_from_instance = lambda Item: "%s" % (Item.tipo)

      class Meta:
          model = Orcamento
          fields = ["quantidade", "tipo_id", "produto_id" ]
```

My views.py

```
def orcamento(request):
        form = OrcamentoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
               form.save()
               return render_to_response("webSite/teste.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response("webSite/orcamento.html", {"form": form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

With `if form.is_valid():` in `views.py`, don't save form in table mysql.

Help-me :(

Comment: Try `form.save()` instead of `form.save`

Comment: first question in stackoverflow, I'm a little lost :(

Comment: First - fix a markdown of your question. As you can see, some code lines are dropped

Comment: You need to indent your code by 4 spaces for it to appear correctly (the editor is using markdown)

Comment: So, what do you have? When you save a form, data does not appear in database? Do you have any errors raised?

Comment: Well, the form is obviously not valid. If you restore `form.is_valid()` and output `{{ form.errors }}` in your template, you'll be able to see why.

Comment: when using if_validation(): Can not go to teste.html and it does not save the form in mysql, if use if_validation(): it's the error "could not be changed because the data did not validate." and not saved in the mysql ... what happens is that the produto type and on Tipo are foreignKey tables Produto and Item, but I use a queryset these two fields in the template orcamento.html (for the user to choose the types registered by adm), is giving some conflict with the uuid the name of the fields: ( (Obs: sorry my bad english :( )

Comment: *Because the form is not valid!* In which case you want it to go back to orcamento.html and show the errors.

Comment: to add {{ form.erros }} in my template and worked ... i saw one post with this  information, but not worked, but now worked

Answer (score 4):

If form is not getting saved when you perform a check of `form.is_valid()` means the form was invalid. In such cases, we should display the errors found by the form for every field. For that to happen, first you should pass form data to templates, if form is invalid.

```
#views.py
def orcamento(request):
    form = OrcamentoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response("webSite/teste.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    #Following will run in all cases except when form was valid
    return render_to_response("webSite/orcamento.html", {"form": form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You can display all the errors thrown by the form or field-wise errors in your template. See the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) detailed understanding.

Comment: yep ... I did it appear in the form errors ....erros in template     tipo_id
        This field is required.
    produto_id
        This field is required.

Comment: is problem in foreignkey with ModelMultipleChoiceField ... :9 ... but not discovery solution :(

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred when I mistyped
`.is_valid()` as `.is_valied()`.
You might wanna check whether it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you never included the `()` in `.is_valid()`. Having the validity checker as `.is_valid:` also raises the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me but I solved by adding parentheses to is_valid and it became is_valid() and the error went and never come back